# Incrementing cell reference number by 12 columns

Tags: excel

I have some cells that are coloured based on the value of some referenced cells in Excel:

[image: Table of coloured cells]

As you can see, 'A', 'B', and 'C' refer to several sheets within the workbook. So you type in the name of the sheet at the top row like 'A' (circled), and then the cells for rows a, b, and c colour themselves in based on the values of a table within that sheet. So for A:

[image: Table of values to reference]

All of those cells in the table are referenced via the INDIRECT and TEXT functions.

My problem is that I currently have to make an absolute reference to the top row (i.e. 'A') in 'Summary' in order to pick out the right sheet (which is also named 'A'). But then I cannot copy and paste this to make another entry (e.g. 'D') without having to manually type in the cell for that entry for every colour formatting rule.

So I want to say 'Excel, pick out the same cell 'A' while in the current entry (for rows a, b, c, and total), and then select the cell 12 columns along for the next entry' for every colour formatting rule. Is there any way of doing this?

Hope this makes sense. And no, I'm not a fan of using Excel for this, but this is what I'm stuck with. Please feel free to ask for clarification. I cannot use VBA (as it is a security risk).

An example of a colour formatting rule is, for row 'a', column '1':

Turn green if the following is true: `=INDIRECT($E$8 & "!" & "C" & TEXT(E14+1, "0"), TRUE)>=a_Score_Upper` (where $E$8 refers to the entry's name, circled red above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX` and calculate a column number based on current colum and increment by 12's.  Like this

Replace `$E$8` with

```
INDEX(8:8,1,INT((COLUMN()-5)/12)*12+5)
```

Comment: Well done - could you maybe expand this answer to explain the thinking behind that line for future viewers?

Let me make sure I understand this - your table is the entire row 8 (8:8), your row number is 1 (as there is only one row), and the last bit is effectively doing modulo arithmetic on the column number. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, why the 5? Is that because I start at column E?

Comment: @DanielSoutar Yes to both